# Firebreath plugin with external DLL not loading on browser start

Tags: plugins, dll, npapi, firebreath

I have a functional plugin developed with the firebreath framework. I'm trying to extend it, i've added a DLL and followed the steps for adding files to the WiX installer. The plugin DLL and the two supporting DLLs are installed. 
I ran dependency walker and my support DLLs are being loaded properly. (there are missing dependancies any I have no idea what these are, at bottom)

When I start any browser the plugin is not listed.

- I don't know how to debug this any further.
- Is there a browser plugin startup log?
- What areas besides dependency loading can I look into with this type of plugin problem?

Missing dependancies: (what are the API-MS-CORE libs? do I need to worry about these missing dependancies? I've heard they are due to dependency walker being out of date)

- API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-0.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-0.DLL
- DCOMP.DLL
- GPSVC.DLL
- IESHIMS.DLL (I know this one is found in the browser environment)

Thanks

Joel

Comment: where are you installing the dependent DLLs to?

Comment: Your dlls must be in the same folder where your plugin dll is located. Check dependency walker for any other dependency issues other than your external dlls.

Comment: The DLLs are installed in the same directory as my NPAPI DLL. And Dependancy walker loads them. There are some dependancies that aren't found... I have no idea what they are though. I'll add them in my question body above.

Comment: I've seen a few posts about these API-MS-WIN*.DLLs being red herrings because dependency walker is out dated. So Im still wondering how to debug a plugin not registering.

Comment: Those dependency issues won't affect plugin loaded. You can use IE compatibility test tool or process monitor to get a better idea why the plugin is not loaded.